# Issue using Cells().formula

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I'm attempting to input a formula into a column in a table. The formula uses the table headers to solve for a result. the location used in the Cells() command also uses a variable as seen below:

```
Sheet6.Cells(17, k + 7).Formula = "=[@[Net Weight]]/([Length] * $J$10 * $J$10)"
Range(Cells(17, k + 7).Address()).Select
```

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line?

Comment: the first line and its an "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: does the formula work if you manually put it in the cell?

Comment: yes,  I took off the brackets and @ sign from the length and it works in the cell but not in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, *if* I make sure that the cell is in the table or next to it. If I put it in a random cell it results in the same error as you get.